# Parsing a raw Protocol Buffer byte stream in C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Given a protocol buffer encoded `Stream` or `byte[]` but NOT knowing the object type itself, how can we print the skeleton of the message? The use case is for debugging IO that's protobuf based, for root cause analysis.

If there are existing tools that can parse the raw Protocol Buffer byte stream from a binary file - that would be great! An alternative could be using the ProtoBuf.NET class `ProtoReader()` to keep chugging along till we hit the error but the usage of ProtoReader() isn't clear. I started as below but couldn't find good documentation on how to use the `ProtoReader` class to actually do it. The source code of the project wasn't very straightforward to follow either ... so would appreciate some tips/help

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    using (var pr = new ProtoReader(fs, TypeModel.Create(), null))
    {
        // Use ProtoReader to march through the bytes
        // Printing field number, type, size and payload values/bytes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, note that the google "protoc" command-line tool has options to try to disassemble a raw message without schema information. With protobuf-net, you can do something like below - but I need to emphasize that *without the schema*, the format is ambiguous: there are more data types/formats than there are "wire types" (the actual encoding formats). Here I am just showing *possible* interpretations, but there are other ways of parsing the same data.

```
static void WriteTree(ProtoReader reader)
{
    while (reader.ReadFieldHeader() > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.FieldNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.WireType);
        switch (reader.WireType)
        {
            case WireType.Variant:
                // warning: this appear to be wrong if the 
                // value was written signed ("zigzag") - to
                // read zigzag, add: pr.Hint(WireType.SignedVariant);
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInt64());
                break;
            case WireType.String:
                // note: "string" here just means "some bytes"; could
                // be UTF-8, could be a BLOB, could be a "packed array",
                // or could be sub-object(s); showing UTF-8 for simplicity
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
                break;
            case WireType.Fixed32:
                // could be an integer, but probably floating point
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadSingle());
                break;
            case WireType.Fixed64:
                // could be an integer, but probably floating point
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadDouble());
                break;
            case WireType.StartGroup:
                // one of 2 sub-object formats
                var tok = ProtoReader.StartSubItem(reader);
                WriteTree(reader);
                ProtoReader.EndSubItem(tok, reader);
                break;
            default:
                reader.SkipField();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

or in v3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64621670/23354

Comment: Marc, that's great. Given your experience can you also suggest usage of Google's `protoc`? I just couldn't find documentation on it. I did use `--decode_raw` but it's unclear how to pass it a binary array (eg: .bin file)...

Comment: `Failed to parse input.` with `protoc` as before even though ProtoBuf is able to read the binary file/stream just fine. Thought I might be missing some format or parameter but guess now. Nevermind, I'll just use the ProtoBuf.NET code. Thanks!

Comment: @user100003 if you think the data is a sub-object, then you basically use **exactly** the same code that is shown in `StartGroup` - i.e. `StartSubItem`, `WriteTree`, `EndSubItem`. The more correct way to do this is to get the data as a `byte[]` (`ProtoReader.AppendBytes`), and then **test** whether it parses correctly as (separately) a UTF-8 string, a sub-message, etc.